# Shell Script - inserir variavel em um comando

Tags: script, shell

Olá, primeiramente quero dizer que sou iniciante em shell script.
Minha duvida é: tenho um script que executará uma série de comandos, um destes comandos é um "input" em que solicita que eu digite um nome, gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de criar uma variavél contendo este nome e quando o comando pedir este nome será inserido.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar parâmetros para isto, por exemplo ao executar:

```
./script_teste parametro_1 parametro_2
```

Sendo `script_teste` o script bash abaixo:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Parametros passados:'
echo '$1 =' $1
echo '$2 =' $2
```

A saída seria:

```
Parametros passados:
$1 = parametro_1
$2 = parametro_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas se for necessário input poderia utilizar o read.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Input: " input # A opção -p faz com que possa digitar na mesma linha

echo "${input}" # Utilizar a variável entre chaves para proteger
```